# Network drives not shown on some users. Explorer need to be restarted

Tags: windows, group-policy, mappeddrive, unc

we have windows domain, with a gpo where the drives are mapped, one of the users just one, has the problem the drives are not shown or disappears after a time. Strangely if you use any other programms or type the correct path you see them/works.

So you basically just dont see them with the windows explorer, they are mapped with the correct letter and evrything. For time being i gave the user a simple batch to restart the explorer.exe.

The user is using windows 10 with the latest updates. I had just one time just simliar issue where the cloned machine had this issue right at start after joining the domain. (I guess i used the same cloned image on this user too, but the other users never had this kind of problem)

Comment: All of that and not include the result of typing in the "drive letter" in Windows Explorer? Or if Explorer is started using a switch to focus on the "drive letter"? Or if you type in the UNC path of the target location in Explorer?

Comment: You can type G:\ or \\server\G, works both. Only the windows-explorer is not showing it at side panel or workplace where all drives are. You really need open the taskmanager and restart "Windows explorer"